# Maven Failsafe Integration Test Classpath

Tags: spring, maven, properties, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have an spring application which reads properties file content from etcd server and then writes the content of that into applications properties file. After that I use that properties file to load my propertyManager.

Code implementation is done but when I try to create integration-tests, there is an small problem:

I use MyClass.class.getResource(configFilePath) to get URL of my properties file and since it points to a file inside of a JAR file while working integration tests. I can't write what I read from etcd server to my properties file since its in JAR file(under target) now.

I tried to add **additionalClasspathElement** ${project.build.directory}\conf to my classpath and use properties file inside of that folder but its not working.

Is there a way for me to change classpath of integration test via failsafe plugin?

Note: Springs etcd support is not want I want to use. I want to change my classpath  when I run my integration tests.

Comment: Reading from etcd ok but then writing to application.properties sounds weird cause spring boot supports etcd ...and of course you come to the point that you can't write the application.properties cause it's inside a jar which can't be changed.

Comment: @khmarbaise  I want to load propertyManager from my .properties file. I dont want to use springs etcd support.